# Equivalent to NoScript for Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox

NoScript is no longer supported under Firefox Quantum. What other methods exist to allow scripts to run on a per-domain basis?

Comment: If you use a lot of addons, I'd recommend switching to Firefox ESR for the time being. That's what I do.

Answer (score 4):

You could try **[uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/umatrix/)** which offers all that NoScript has, but even more granular. That means a little learning (dealing with uMatrix is a bit different), but also more flexibility. To give you an idea, here's a screenshot taken from the addons page:

[image: uMatrix]

Looking at this for a few seconds you will note that other than with NoScript, with *uMatrix* you can even say "allow JS from foo.com when asked for by example.com" – instead of only "allow JS from foo.com". And you certainly see what the term "Matrix" refers to. What it seems to *not* offer is "allow for this session" – but if I understood correctly, that's its default mode: to make changes permanent, you'll need to "lock" (save) them (see the lock icon at the top).

The addon is from the same dev as *uBlock Origin* and often recommended by experts *for advanced users.*

PS: If you saved (exported) your NoScript configuration, you even can [import its whiltelist entries](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

> NoScript is no longer supported under Firefox Quantum.

If you read the [NoScript webpage](https://noscript.net/) you will see that they are aware of the issue and plan to have it resolved shortly:

> #### Where's NoScript for Firefox 57 "Quantum"?
>
> 2017-11-14: We're [working hard to make NoScript for Quantum available](https://hackademix.net/2017/11/14/double-noscript/)
>   to you as soon as possible, definitely by the end of this week.